# If $\psi$ is the density of the wrapped normal distribution on $[0,1)$, is $x\mapsto\int_{[0,\:1)}\lambda({\rm d}y)\frac{f(y)}{\psi(y-x)}$ constant?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, normal-distribution

Let $\sigma>0$, $$\phi(x):=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12\left|\frac x\sigma\right|^2}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R,$$ $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $$\mathcal N(x,B):=\int_B\lambda({\rm d}y)\varphi(y-x)\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in\mathbb R\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R).$$ If $$\iota:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor,$$ then the wrapped normal distribution kernel on $[0,1)$ with variance $\sigma^2$ is defined by $$\mathcal W(x,\;\cdot\;):=\mathcal N(x,\;\cdot\;)\circ\iota^{-1}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in[0,1).$$ If $$\psi(x):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\phi(x+k)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R,$$ we can show that $$\mathcal W(x,B)=\int_B\lambda({\rm d}y)\psi(y-x)\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in[0,1)\times\mathcal B([0,1))\tag1.$$

> Given a bounded Borel measurable $f:[0,1)\to[0,\infty)$, can we show that $$[0,1)\ni x\mapsto\int_{[0,\:1)}\lambda({\rm d}y)\frac{f(y)}{\psi(y-x)}\tag2$$ is constant?

Intuitively, I think that this claim could hold by the circular nature of $\psi$, but I don't know an easy way to prove or disprove this.

Comment: @Xi'an No further constraint, yes. But if you have a sensible constraint under which you know a proof, feel free to impose this constraint.

Comment: @Xi'an Maybe it's useful to note that this question is motivated by https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/455707/222528.

Comment: @Xi'an I don't really expect it, but it would be very useful for me if it would be the case. I've described the motivation for that in the linked question (stats.stackexchange.com/q/455707/222528).

Comment: Take $f\equiv 1$. Since the function $y\mapsto \psi(y-x)$ periodic with period 1, the integral is constant. This extends to periodic functions with period 1.

Comment: @Xi'an Okay, you're using that $\lambda^{\otimes d}_{[0,\:1)}({\rm d}y)f(y)g(y-x)=\int_{[-x,\:1-x)}\lambda^{\otimes d}({\rm d}y)f(y+x)g(y)$ for all Borel measurable $f:[0,1)^d\to[0,\infty)$ and $g:\mathbb R^d\to[0,\infty)$. Now, the $f$ I've got in mind can be extended to an $1$-periodic function $(1=(1,\ldots,1)$) on $\mathbb R^d$, but I don't think that this helps.